# Dispose Image - Out of Memory C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory, emgucv, dispose

I have a code like below. I want convert the image from `picture-box` to apply `median-filter` by EmguCV. And the problem is that the "out of memory" problem occurs even though I dispose the image. After I click many button handler, the first line occurs show the problem. Please help me!

```
Bitmap bm1 = new Bitmap(imgBox.Image); //Out of memory
Image<Gray, byte> EmguImage1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(bm1);
EmguImage = EmguImage1.SmoothMedian(1);
imgBox.Image.Dispose();
imgBox.Image = EmguImage1.Bitmap;
bm1.Dispose();
EmguImage1.Dispose();
```

Comment: In which line does the OutOfMemoryException occurs?

Comment: @scher I edited it! The exception occurs in the first line

Comment: So disposing takes no effect, when the exception occures prior to it. How big is the Image?

Comment: @scher the image is from 13 to 16Mb

Comment: If the image is jpeg or png or any other compressed format it gets uncompressed while loading it in the `Bitmap`. So the size might by much larger then then the compressed.

Comment: @scher I know that but the problem is that whether the way I dispose the image correctly or not.

Comment: Do you get it the first time when you call this code, or later

Comment: No, I get it to many time later. 5 or 6 first times, I don't get it but It occurs when more than 6 times.